# How to validate phone number in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I format my script and input to show only 10 numbers and have the characters of ( ) and + at the start of the number? Thanks.

Comment: use regular expression - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can use a patern attribute something like:

```
<input type="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" required="">
```